# DataBricks QueryEndpointInput field name not a JsonParameter

Tags: java, databricks

The DataBricks Java SDK has a class called QueryEndpointInput.
That has a field called name.  It is the only field in the library that is
not annotated with @JsonParameter.
When we call

```
databricksWorkspaceClient.servingEndpoints().query(queryEndpointInput);
```

It fails because the Json serializer serializes the name field anyway, and then DataBricks deserializer fails because it does not recognize the field "name".

Reverting back a few revisions, one at a time, in the SDK does not fix it.

One possibility might be the serializer global settings.  Has anyone else seen this issue?

Java 17, DataBricks SDK Java 0.19.0 (and 0.15.0 is the same)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out rev 0.19.0 of the DataBricks Java Library had a bug.
An update fixed it.